# Update One ViewModel Property from another viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I am working with MVVM application using MVVM light. Here I have 2 Views and related ViewModels like Header and Orders

```
 public ObservableCollection<HeaderViewModel> HeaderControls
    {
        get { return _header ?? (_header = new ObservableCollection<HeaderViewModel>()); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> ViewControls
    {
        get { return _viewControls ?? (_viewControls = new ObservableCollection<object>()); }
    }
```

I am loading these ViewModels in observable collection to load related views.

```
  private void LoadControls()
    {
        this.HeaderControls.Clear();
        var headerViewModel = new HeaderViewModel();
        this.HeaderControls.Add(headerViewModel);

        this.ViewControls.Clear();
        var orderViewModel = new OrdersViewModel();
        this.ViewControls.Add(orderViewModel);
    }
```

Now OrderViewModels have few properties like text fields, grid, those I want to update via click of icons on HeaderViewModel.

I have also tried the solution posted on, but it does not helped : [Accessing Properties in other ViewModels in MVVM Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913077/accessing-properties-in-other-viewmodels-in-mvvm-light)

Answer (score 0):

Communication in MVVM Light between Model<->VM<->View's are normally via the `Messenger` class.

In short, the `Messenger` allows you to send a "message"(could be a string, int, pretty much any type you want) from one class to another. The receiver subscribes to receive these message(either based on type of message it wants to get or via a combination of who sends it and the type). Similarly the sender can also just send a message to a specific other class or to anyone who is subscribed to the type of the message.

One of the main advantage's of the `Messenger` is it's based on weak dependency hence you don't have to create a strong dependency between something like VM<->View, thereby staying true to MVVM principles. It's also well documented and you should be able to get ample help in "how to use it" from links such as:

[MVVM Light - what's the Messenger?](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mvvm-light-whats-messenger)

[MVVM Light Toolkit Messenger V2](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx)

[or even this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994523/1834662)

as I've mentioned in that answer, one of the concepts shown by the download example in it is "Messenger class usage with a custom message type OpenWindowMessage". You can see how the message being sent is a custom type and how VM's subscribe/send and act on these messages.

**Side-note:**

From the code you've posted it's hard to say this for sure but it seems pretty weird you creating a `ObservableCollection<object> ViewControls`. I see you're adding a `OrdersViewModel` to it, so why aint the type just `OrdersViewModel` for the collection or even `ViewModelBase`. All your VM's should be inheriting from `ViewModelBase` anyways.