# WPF MVVM - Accessing properties of other ViewModels using delegates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `MainViewModel`, which features `PersonViewModel` and a `HouseViewModel` as properties. `HouseViewModel` has the property `GetRooms`. What is the best way to access this property from the `PersonViewModel`?

My solution at the minute is to pass through an instance of `MainViewModel` to `PersonViewModel`, then I can call `MainViewModel.HouseViewModel.GetRooms`. However, this seems a little wasteful.

I am happy to pass a function as a delegate, but I can't seem to do this with a Property. I have searched for an example of this and only come up with overly complicated techniques. I'm assuming there must be a simple way of doing this, as it seems like a common problem. Can anyone point out a strong example?

Or is there another, alternative method that I haven't considered?

Comment: Isn't it more logical that a person gets a room? A house doesn't get a room? A house has rooms that can be 'got' by a person? So why does the House object have a method get a room? Surely the Person object should have that.

Comment: This is a fictional example. Please ignore any sort of perceived logic between Person/House/Room.

Comment: Ah ok, then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913077/accessing-properties-in-other-viewmodels-in-mvvm-light

Comment: `However, this seems a little wasteful.?` What do you mean by this? I feel you can pass HouseViewModel as parameter to PersonViewModel Construction instead of the MainViewModel. If it makes sense to do this - do it, dont over optimize it and it will lead to confusion. Sometimes readability is more important.

Comment: Fair enough, but where do you draw the line? What if I need to pass the MainViewModel down through several instances of classes?

Comment: Also, Paul Zahra - is that solution not specific to MVVM-Light?

Answer (score 2):

If a method has to be shared across two viewmodel, it should be defined in base viewmodel or a service. The best way is a common Service class should hold all common methods like GetRooms, CheckIn, CheckOut, etc. And this service should be provided to every viewmodel using [Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx).

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel(IRoomService roomservice)
    {

    }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel(IRoomService roomservice)
    {

    }
}
```